# How to add an anonymous instance off a class as an ActionListener

Tags: java, class, oop

Im working on a lab that requires me to make a JFrame with 2 inner classes. One that entends JPanel, has a text area and a jbutton. And another that implements action listener. How do i add an anonymouse instance of the second class to my JButton that is already in an inner class. Here is the brief to get a better understanding.

[image]

here is the code i have written so far. I can get the Frame to appear, but the JPanel doesnt appear, nor does the JButtons or JTextArea.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FormFrame extends JFrame
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new FormFrame();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}   
public FormFrame()
{
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();

    RegisterPanel p = new RegisterPanel();
    p.button.addActionListener(new SubmitResponder());
    //
    // Here is where im lost...
    //


    contentPane.add(p);
    setSize(300, 200);
    setVisible(true);
}

class RegisterPanel extends JPanel
{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField text = new JTextField();
    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");     
}

class SubmitResponder implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()== RegisterPanel.button) //Asks me to make button static here
        {

            //Shows "No enclosing instance of the type FormFrame.RegisterPanel is accessible in scope"
                RegisterPanel.this.text.setText("Submit Complete");

        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: You can't use `RegisterPanel.this` within a class that isn't a `RegisterPanel`

Comment: @cricket_007 care to elaborate?

Comment: You have that line of code within `class SubmitResponder`, thus the error, because there is "No enclosing instance of the type FormFrame.RegisterPanel" within the class of `SubmitResponder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the `RegisterPanel` instance to the action listener:

```
class SubmitResponder implements ActionListener {

    private final RegisterPanel rp;

    public SubmitResponder(RegisterPanel rp) {
        this.rp = rp;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        rp.text.setText("Submit Complete");
    }
}
```

There's no need to check the source btw. The AL is only listening to 1 source.

```
RegisterPanel p = new RegisterPanel();
p.button.addActionListener(new SubmitResponder(p));
```

Comment: Im not using an anonymous inner class, im creating an anonymous instance of a class already writing (that `implements ActionListener`)

Comment: This makes sense, but the JButton and TextField still dont appear. Do they need to be added to anything besides `p` being added to the `contentPane`?

Comment: @Aaronward Yes, right now nothing is rendering them, the ```JFrame``` renders it's childrens, one of which is ```p```, then ```p``` will render it's children. You need to make the ```JButton``` and ```JTextField``` children of ```p``` by adding them to ```this``` in the constructor: ```this.add(child)``` or just ```add(child)``` for short.

Comment: i figured it out, i had to write `p.add(p.button)` and `p.add(p.text)` then add it to the contentPane

Answer (score 1):

```
p.button.addActionListener(new SubmitResponder());
```

Here the `SubmitResponder` is already an anonymous instance, quite literally, because it has no name.

Your error about "no enclosing instance" is unrelated. Since `SubmitResponder` is not an inner class of `RegisterPanel` (it's a sibling) it doesn't belong to an instance of `RegisterPanel` and so it cannot logically refer to `RegisterPanel.this`. How would it know which instance that is? There might be many, or even zero, depending on how many the parent `FormFrame` decides to create. It so happens that there's only one, but that's not the point. On the other hand if you said `FormFrame.this` there would be no doubt what that meant no matter the code did, unless `RegisterPanel` stopped being an inner class or it became static. Does that make sense?

To do what you want, the `SubmitResponder` needs to talk to `RegisterPanel` via a method in `FormFrame`. Incidentally you don't actually need to say `FormFrame.this.doSomething()` unless `SubmitResponder` also has a method called `doSomething`.

Comment: That part i have down, but its accessing the components in the RegisterPanel class from the instance is the problem im having..

Comment: I've edited to explain what's going on and how you can solve the problem. Jorn's solution is also sensible.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions tell you that the `RegisterPanel` should be a field in the `FormFrame` class, which you haven't done. Something like this:

```
public class FormFrame extends JFrame
{
    RegisterPanel panel;
    ...

    public FormFrame()
    {
        panel = new RegisterPanel();
        ...
    }

    ...

    class SubmitResponder implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == panel.button)
            {
                panel.text.setText(...);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can access `panel` from inside the `SubmitResponder` class.

---

As a side note, the instructions are using some terminology in an ambiguous and incorrect way:

- "Anonymous instance" is not an official term with a precise meaning.
- Using official definitions, "class field" would imply the `static` modifier. Given the context of the assignment, I doubt that's correct. It should probably have said "instance field".

Comment: Its the JButton thats the problem, even if i make it global, i cant create a new instant of it without making it local to `RegisterPanel`

Comment: Please see my edit. Also note that the other two answers don't follow the instructions for the assignment.